# Selenium js webdriver doesn't open extension pop-up while in headless mode

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, walletextension

I have a selenium js testing script for a web3 platform. The flow is : adding the extension to the browser, going to the extension's welcome page, setting up the wallet, going back to the platform, connecting the wallet and the rest of the actions.

On headful mode, everything works as it should. While using headless mode, when i click on the wallet anchor, it does not open my extension pop-up in another tab. It only updates my button's text to "Connecting.." and a spinning loader appears. I have no errors or warnings, it just gets stuck there until my script fails because it doesn't find the "Sign" button.

Using other anchors I can open new tabs, extensions work properly (tested with a font extension), and as I said, it works well in headful mode.

I am debugging it with chrome://inspect and `options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");`